# How to send form to firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

In flutter, I created the following code that allows the user to add the number of units he wants (many forms), then it sends all the information to firebase at one time, the code works correctly but I have one problem when the user sends the form  I receive a many form in the firebase. How do I change this code so that the user can send the information he entered to firebase at one time (multi widgets in one form)?

```
class _UnitesPageState extends State<UnitesPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

var _myWidgets = <Widget>[];
int _index = 0;

final unitesnumber = [
  ' unite 1  ',' unite 2  ',' unite 3  ',

];

bool autoValidate = true;
GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

final Map<int, String> namesvalues = Map();
final Map<int, String> unitesvalues = Map();

final List<TextEditingController> _namesControllers = [];
final List<TextEditingController> _unitesControllers = [];


void _add() {
  int keyValue = _index;
  _myWidgets = List.from(_myWidgets)
    ..add(Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _names(keyValue),
          _unites(keyValue),
        ],
      ),
    ));

  setState(() => ++_index);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final bottomNavigationBar = Container(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
            label: const Text(' SEND',
                )),
          onPressed: () async {
               setState(() {
                 autoValidate = !autoValidate;
               });
                 for (var i = 0; i < _myWidgets.length; i++) {
                   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').add({
                       "names": _namesControllers[i].text,
                    "unites":_unitesControllers[i].text,
                     
   });
                 }
               }
            ),
      ],
    ),
  );
  
  return Scaffold(
   // appBar
    bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    body:Padding(
      child: Form(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildfaculte(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: ListView(
                        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                        children: _myWidgets,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),),
    ),
  );
}


Widget _names(int keyValue) {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  _namesControllers.add(controller);
  return FormBuilderTextField(
    name: 'names',
    controller: controller,
  );
}

Widget _unites(int keyValue) {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  _unitesControllers.add(controller);
  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
        return unitesnumber.where((suggestion) =>
            suggestion.toLowerCase().contains(value.text.toLowerCase()));
      },
      onSelected: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedUnites = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  );
}

}
```

Comment: Your are creating one document by names. It's not possible to write multiple documents at once. And don't forget the await key word before FirebaseFirestore.instance.

Comment: Thanks can you provide me some code!

Comment: @mariofrancois You can definitely write multiple documents 'at one time' using a batched write (or transaction where they are all written or it fails). OP; Firestore has no 'forms' or 'widgets' -  only Collections, Documents and Fields so sending 'Forms' is a little unclear. It's also not clear why data has to be written 'at one time' - why can't you just write each document sequentially? If you do need to write them at once, it's covered in the documentation [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)

Comment: @Jay Thank you for let me know Batched.